# How to change Zabbix agent in order to monitor tls secured Docker daemon socket

Tags: docker, openssl, zabbix

I've already make my my host Docker daemon protected by the steps in [this official page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/). However my zabbix agent does not work. It was monitored status of the docker containers by the following module enabled in file `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf.d/docker.conf`:

```
LoadModule=zabbix_module_docker.so
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by adding docker socket, **`/var/run/docker.sock`**, to the daemon's hosts list:

```
dockerd --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=server-cert.pem --tlskey=server-key.pem -H=0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Just this!